# Get players inventory and then broadcast the item displayname

Tags: java, module, minecraft, bukkit

Ok, Im trying to check the player's inventory when they login and it it say that displayname

```
public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
    Player p = event.getPlayer();

    for (int i = 0; i < p.getInventory().getSize(); i++) {
        if (p.getInventory().getItem(i).getType() != null) {
            if (!p.getInventory().getItem(i).getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equals("KITS")){
                Bukkit.broadcastMessage(i.getItemMeta().getDisplayName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's just causing error.

Error log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at me.BlueJelly.MPSKitPvP.Listeners.PlayerListener.onPlayerJoin(PlayerListener.jav
a:31) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_09]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_09]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_09]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:425) ~[
   craftbukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.6.4-R2.0-9-g68d0e57-b2930jnks]
```

I know it's a NullPointerException but i don't know how it can say that.
I hope you understands what i wrote...

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't know how it can say that"? One of the references must be null - you need to find out which. Are you able to use a debugger when executing this code?

Comment: But i have a i == null it should not say anything if i have that, or?

Comment: Well `i` can't be null - it's an `int`. And the code you've written doesn't include that anyway... but `p` could be null, or `p.getInventory()` could be null... (etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many potential places in your code for a NullPointerException.

For example:

```
p.getInventory().getItem(i).getType()
```

Use the reported line number (31) to find the exact line.
If you can't debug the code, use logs (or simple souts) to find the null reference.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [the documentation](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/inventory/Inventory.html), I believe instead of `p.getInventory().getItem(i).getType() != null` it should be `p.getInventory().getItem(i)!= null` as if there is no Item stack in that slot trying to get its type will throw an npe

Comment: Additionally, I think it's possible for an ItemStack to have a null ItemMeta